# How does Android logger supports multiprocess file write synchronization?

Tags: android, multithreading, logging

Looking at the Android logger framework it is clear the all application writes into a same device file `/dev/log/main`for main buffer.It is a character device file.

Android logging library source code is located [here](https://gitorious.org/android-enablement/system-core/source/e2bf2ea4d2846031edfc52b942ad53e5467243f6%3aliblog). According to the code there is no process based file write synchronization except thread synchronization using pthread lock.

My question is that :

How does across process file write synchronization happens in this logging model?

Is it because of restricted buffer size write?